# Html page is not showing full in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I need Help, as my html page is showing only half height in Mobile page view. in browser it looks ok but in mobile view only half a page is being displayed.

```css
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.adds {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fluidMedia {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* proportion value to aspect ratio 16:9 (9 / 16 = 0.5625 or 56.25%) */
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fluidMedia iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
     color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

sidebar {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<header>
   <h1>Income Tax Act 1961</h1>
</header>
  

<sidebar>

 <div class="fluidMedia">
    <iframe src="http://www.incometaxact1961.com/Income_Tax/Sections/section2.html" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
</div>

</sidebar>


<footer>Copyright &copy; <a href="http://www.incometaxact1961.com/" >Incometaxact1961.com</a></footer>
```

I just need post to display full in mobile and web page.

Any help code will be highly appreciated, I need to load a html page in another html page.

Answer (score 1):

If the enough content does not reach the device's height,it will come like this, You can fix this by two ways.

> Set a **min-height** for the sidebar or make the **footer sticky** to the bottom of the container.

Setting minimum height will vary for different devices.So you need a sticky footer for this case.It is possible in CSS3 using flex layout.Try the given code.

```
html,body{
height: 100%;
}
.container{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100%;
}
header{
 flex: 0 0 auto;
}
sidebar{
 flex: 1 0 auto;
}
footer{
 flex:0 0 auto;
}
```

It will act as sticky footer whenever your content on the page cannot fits the device height.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is giving your footer `position: absolute;` to make it stick to the bottom, like so:

```css
  div.container {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }

    a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .adds {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .fluidMedia {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* proportion value to aspect ratio 16:9 (9 / 16 = 0.5625 or 56.25%) */
        padding-top: 30px;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .fluidMedia iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; 
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    header, footer {
        padding: 1em;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        clear: left;
        text-align: center;
         color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        }

    sidebar {
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding: 1em;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    footer {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">

    <header>
       <h1>Income Tax Act 1961</h1>
    </header>
      

    <sidebar>

     <div class="fluidMedia">
        <iframe src="http://www.incometaxact1961.com/Income_Tax/Sections/section2.html" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
    </div>

    </sidebar>


    <footer>Copyright &copy; <a href="http://www.incometaxact1961.com/" >Incometaxact1961.com</a></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting initial scale of viewport to 1 by inserting this meta to html head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix your issue yo do not need to add any extra code or CSS properties. Instead, you have to delete a few, in particular, remove these:

```
.fluidMedia {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.fluidMedia iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
}
```

Please, note that I said REMOVE these, not that your CSS should keep them. So this section of your CSS will look like:

```
.fluidMedia {
    /* You can remove this, since it is empty. I added it for clarity purposes */
}

//This is what is left of the iframe CSS properties
.fluidMedia iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I really hope this helps!